# How to test a function that depends on a menu() user input

Tags: r, automated-tests, testthat

Is there a way to automatically test the `menu()` function?

I created a function in a package that requires some user interaction. It basically asks the user whether a result is as desired. I would like to have a `testthat`-body that takes inputs and creates and checks the output. However, the user interaction hampers this framework. Is there any way to insert the user answer programmatically? I tried the `interactive()` function without success.

```
library(testthat)

# fancy function
askPermission <- function(old, new) {
  cat(paste0(old,
             "\n--->\n", new, "\n\n"))
  prompt <- "Use this? "
  response <- menu(c("YES", "NO"), title = prompt) == 1
  return(new)
}

# tests
test_that("test Permission", {
  expect_equal(askPermission("A", "B"), "B")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to not use any further dependency by checking the calling scope. `test_that()` has its own function environment with the name `test_env`. If the function `askPermission()` is called in a nested scope that contains such an environment on any higher level, the `menu()`-function is skipped. Furthermore, `menu()` does only make sense in an interactive context.

```
library(testthat)
# fancy function
askPermission <- function(old, new) {
  cat(paste0(old,
             "\n--->\n", new, "\n\n"))
  prompt <- "Use this? "
  
  # calling scope
  tb <- .traceback(x = 0)

  # check if called in testthat or interactive
  if(!any(unlist(lapply(tb, function(x) any(grepl("test_env", x))))) && interactive())
    response <- menu(c("YES", "NO"), title = prompt) == 1
  
  return(new)
}

# tests
test_that("test Permission", {
  expect_equal(askPermission("A", "B"), "B")
})
#> A
#> --->
#> B
#> 
#> Test passed

# regular usage --------
askPermission("A", "B")
#> A
#> --->
#> B
#> Use this?  
#>   
#>   1: YES
#>   2: NO
#> 
#> Choice:
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra `response` argument, with default value `NA`, and which you could set just to force the response during the test :

```r
library(testthat)

# fancy function
askPermission <- function(old, new , response = NA) {
  cat(paste0(old,
             "\n--->\n", new, "\n\n"))
  prompt <- "Use this? "
 if (is.na(response)) { 
    response <- menu(c("YES", "NO"), title = prompt) == 2
  } 
  return(new)
}

# tests
library(testthat)
test_that("test Permission", {
  expect_equal(askPermission("A", "B",2), "B")
})
#> A
#> --->
#> B
#> 
#> Test passed
```

Another option is to use the [`mockr`](https://github.com/krlmlr/mockr) package to mock the `menu` function:

```r
library(testthat)
library(mockr)

local({
  # Here, we override the menu function to force expected choice
  local_mock(menu = function(choices,title=NULL) 2)
  
  test_that("test Permission", {
    expect_equal(askPermission("A", "B"), "B")
  })
})
#> A
#> --->
#> B
#> 
#> Test passed
```

Note that the `AskPermission` function you provided as example always returns `new` and doesn't depend on `response`

Comment: Well that is actually my current workaround but I am not happy with this solution since I do have to include an argument just for testing purposes :/

Comment: And what about the second proposed solution?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the scond part. Thanks for pointing me to this package. I'll have a look

Comment: did `mockr` help?

Comment: Thank ypu for your effort. I had othe rproblems to solve and just came back to this topic. I appreciate your solution yet prefered a way to not use another package.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and for sharing your solution